# AVR ATMega169P LCD display using C++

Tags: c++, avr, atmelstudio

I am trying to display something to the LCD screen on an ATMega 169P microcontroller. When using C, I am able to use this code:

```
char str[50];
int value = 100;
str = sprintf(str, "some text %d", value);
LCD_puts(str);
```

and it will display fine. LCD_puts is a method given to us by my teacher.
However, I am trying to use C++ for my assignment, and I cannot get LCD_puts() to work. I've used sprintf and snprintf and I receive the following compiler error when using snprintf. The code I am using is below also. (Apologies for the formatting, I cannot post pictures).

```
char str[100];
int rpm = 100; //Genaric value

snprintf(str, 100, '%d in',rpm);
LCD_puts(str);
```

invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'unint8_t*' {aka unsigned char*}'[-fpermissive]

I don't think my exact code is required, I only need to know why this error would be caused and if there is a C++ function that is the equivalent to sprintf that I could use. I will post my exact code if needed however.

Comment: Your version of `snprintf` must be non-standard if it requires `uint8_t*` See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf For the second parameter, you should tie it to your array `str` somehow instead of using a magic number, so that if `str` changes size, the value is updated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to store an unsigned char array into a signed char array. Either declare str as unsigned char:

```
unsigned char str[100];
```

or cast str in the argument as unsigned char:

```
snprintf((uint8_t*)str, 100, '%d in',rpm);
```

In this case `uint8_t` and `unsigned char` are equivalent.